# Dependencies between maven projects

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a few libraries which are used as dependencies in other projects. Is there a way to see which projects are using my libraries?

Comment: How do you know that your libraries are used as dependencies in other projects?

Answer (score 0):

Search for group & artifact id in pom.xml of other projects.